# Javascript Array manipulation to return intersection of elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, data-structures

I have a javascript array of `productIds = [3, 4, 5, 8]` like this.
Now each ProductId has its own compatible Product.

```
    3 has compatible Product -> 5, 7
    4 has compatible Product -> 7, 9
    5 has compatible Product -> 7, 1, 2
    8 has compatible Product -> 7, 4, 2
```

Now the intersection should be product 7 so it should return 7.
Also the productIds array can have length n = 0 to 12. Can anyone suggest a solution.

Input productIds = [3, 4, 5, 8]

Sql table for CompatibleProducts

| id | productId | compatibleId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 7 |
| 3 | 4 | 7 |
| 4 | 4 | 9 |
| 5 | 5 | 7 |
| 6 | 5 | 1 |
| 7 | 5 | 2 |
| 8 | 8 | 7 |
| 9 | 8 | 4 |
| 10 | 8 | 2 |

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far.

Comment: And your source data.

Comment: @MarkBaijens have posted my compatibleProduct table

Comment: @VishalKumar Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: So, if the count of CompatibleProducts matches the Input length, you need those CompatibleProducts?

Comment: Your SQL table is not a format that we can use to solve the problem, not directly.  Please show us what your inputs to the function would be.  One would presumably be the product ids you want to combine (`[3, 4, 5, 8]`) (or is that also supposed to be derived from that table data?)  And how are you storing the results of your table lookup?   
 Is it something like `{3: [5, 7], 4:[ 7, 9], 5: [7, 1, 2], 8: [7, 4, 2]}`?  Something else?  If you're looking for suggested data structures, please  make that explicit.

Comment: @ScottSauyet it is like this {3: [5, 7], 4:[ 7, 9], 5: [7, 1, 2], 8: [7, 4, 2]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can build this on a function which takes the intersection of a collection of lists.

Here we have `intersectAll`, which is itself built on `intersect`.  Then we simply grab the arrays of compatible values for each product supplied and call `intersectAll`:

```js
const intersect = (xs, ys) => 
  xs .filter (x => ys .includes (x))

const intersectAll = ([x, ...xs]) => 
  x == undefined ? [] : xs .reduce (intersect, x)

const findJointCompatibles = (compatibles, ids) => 
  intersectAll (ids .map (id => compatibles [id] || []))

const compatibles = {3: [5, 7], 4: [7, 9], 5: [7, 1, 2], 8: [7, 4, 2]}

console .log (
  findJointCompatibles (compatibles, [3, 4, 5, 8])
)
```

This makes the assumption that the list of products to check is supplied.  If you want to use everything in your input, then it's even simpler:

```js
const findCompleteCompatibles = (compatibles) => 
  intersectAll (Object .values (compatibles))

findCompleteCompatibles (compatibles) //=> [7]
```

`intersect` and `intersectAll` are genuinely reusable functions that you might keep in a utility library.

---

Note for next time.  Please demonstrate your own attempts when asking a question on StackOverflow.